Problem with creating Highcharts chart instance using .NET Core library after upgrade from 11.4.1 to 11.4.6.4
I am getting a null object error (nothing more specific unfortunately) when creating the chart below using the .NET Core library:
    var chart = new Highcharts
{
    ID = $"chart_{categoryGuid.ToString().Replace("-", "")}",
    Chart = new Chart
    {
        Height = "400",
        Type = ChartType.Column,
        Style = new Hashtable { { "FontFamily", "Segoe UI" } },
        BackgroundColor = "transparent",
    },
    Credits = new Credits { Enabled = false },
    Title = new Title { Text = categoryTitle },
    XAxis =
    [
        new XAxis
        {
            Categories = optionCategoryResults.Select(c => c.optionTitle).ToList(),
            Crosshair = new XAxisCrosshair()
        }
    ],
    YAxis =
    [
        new YAxis
        {
            Title = new YAxisTitle {Text = "Relative Score"},
        }
    ],
    Tooltip = new Tooltip
    {
        Shared = true,
        PointFormat = "<span style=\"color:{point.color}\">\u25CF</span> Score: <b>{point.y:.1f}</b><br/>"
    },
    PlotOptions =
    {
        Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
        {
            Stacking = PlotOptionsColumnStacking.Normal,
            Animation = new Animation
            {
                Duration = 2000,
                Easing = "easeOutBounce"
            }
        }
    },
    Legend =
    {
        Enabled = false
    },
    Series = categoryResultsSeries
};

I've checked that each of the variables I created, such as categoryGuid, categoryTitle, optionCategoryResults, categoryResultsSeries are correct.  I've even tried hard coding them and/or removing them completely (if possible), and still get the same error.
Note that this code works fine with 11.4.1, but does not with 11.4.6, and the highcharts changelog does not show any breaking changes, although clearly there has been.
Any ideas?
EDIT: Adding full stack trace - although it's not particularly helpful as far as I can see:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at ResiliencyAssessment.Helpers.Charting.CreateCategorySummaryScoreChart(Guid categoryGuid, String categoryTitle, OptionCategoryResult[] optionCategoryResults) in D:\LinQuestShare\Resiliency\Code Projects\SMEBasedAssessmentTool\ResiliencyAssessment\Helpers\Charting.cs:line 37

Hi @ProfNimrod, It looks like some object has not been initialized. Could you provide me with the exception stacktrace?

Apols for the delay - I added the full stack trace, but it doesn't really provide any help as far as I can see.

It does help, a lot. What's at line 37 of Charting.cs? Have you tried debugging the code and inspecting the variables used in that line? One of them is null

BTW $"chart_{categoryGuid.ToString().Replace("-", "")}" isn't useful. If you want a GUID as just digits you can specify a format string, eg "chart_" + thatGuid.ToString("N") or String.Format("chart_{0:N},thatGuid); or $"chart_{thatGuid:N}";. If thatGuid is null though, .ToString() will throw a NullReferenceException

Line 37 is the code snippet above, so the stack trace doesn't really help at all, and doesn't help explain why the code works just fine with 11.4.1 and not with 11.4.6.

@ProfNimrod, you provided Exception Description, not StackTrace. In the debugger mode, you need to trigger the error and find the proper field in the exception details.

@ppotaczek That is the full stack trace... like I said it really isn't at all helpful.  The message is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". No code changes were made, just upgraded the library from 11.4.1 to 11.4.6.  Have also tried with 11.4.6.5 and still no joy.

You should create specific objects, not anonymous ones. The below code should work correctly:
var chart = new Highcharts
    {
        ID = $"chart_8",
        Chart = new Chart
        {
            Height = "400",
            Type = ChartType.Column,
            Style = new Hashtable { { "FontFamily", "Segoe UI" } },
            BackgroundColor = "transparent",
        },
        Credits = new Credits { Enabled = false },
        Title = new Title { Text = "categoryTitle" },
        XAxis = new List<XAxis>
        {
            new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new List<string> { "abc" },
                Crosshair = new XAxisCrosshair()
            }
        },
        YAxis = new List<YAxis>
        {
            new YAxis
            {
                Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Relative Score" },
            }
        },
        Tooltip = new Tooltip
        {
            Shared = true,
            PointFormat = "<span style=\"color:{point.color}\">\u25CF</span> Score: <b>{point.y:.1f}</b><br/>"
        },
        PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
        {
            Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
            {
                Stacking = PlotOptionsColumnStacking.Normal,
                Animation = new Animation
                {
                    Duration = 2000,
                    Easing = "easeOutBounce"
                }
            }
        },
        Legend = new Legend
    {
        Enabled = false
    }
};


The question doesn't use anonymous types. They wouldn't affect an NRE anyway. Are you confusing C# 12 collection expressions for anonymous types? XAxis = [ new XAxis{},...] is little different from XAxis = new XAxis[]{ new XAxis{},...} or XAxis = new List<XAxis>{ new XAxis{},...}. The real difference is that collection initialization infers the actual collection type from the target.
